# copypng failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios

I am getting the following error when building my iPhone application. The reddarkedge.png is right there in the supporting files folder.

```
/Users/azamsharp/Desktop/UltraCam/UltraCam/TCam/reddarkedge.pngCommand /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/iPhoneOS Build System Support.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copypng failed with exit code 1
```

Even if I remove the reddarkedge.png from the project it still gives me the same error.

[image]

UPDATE SOLUTION:

Turns out I had to hard delete them.

Comment: There is no code! I am just building the app and I get the above error. The image is not even used anywhere in the application.

Comment: When you dragged this image to your project, did you select "Copy items into destination folder" and select your project as the target for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you say "Even if I remove the reddarkedge.png from the project" when you remove it from the Xcode file navigator does it get removed from the copy bundle step of the target build process? If not maybe manually delete it there as well?

You could also try highl

You might also try opening the XML project file in a text editor and removing the reference by hand. Make sure to have a backup in case you have problems though.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 7):

Had the sameproblem with the CopyPNG error. Place the image in your project again and use the program [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/) over your images, this solved the problem. Maybe it will also solve your problem.

Or

Check the "Copy bundle resources" build stage to see if there are any missing files (png, txt, plist, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time this happens when you missed to check the `Copy items if needed` while adding the images.

Answer (score 0):

I actually referenced the app icon image from Desktop.But, accidentally I deleted that image and got this error. After that I have added the image in the Desktop with same name and build got succeeded. So please make sure that, if you are missing something like this. Hope this will help somebody!!!