# Command copypng failed with exit code 71

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

When I try to build an iOS application the XCode gives me the error which says

```
error: can't exec 'copypng' (No such file or directory)
Command copypng failed with exit code 71
```

So the problem isn't in missing PNG files or something like this, the problem is in the file that should does copy. I met this error for the first time and google says nothing.

How do I fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you stated, that you want to copy file, while there is no such file. Go to Project->Target->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources and find 'copypng' file (should be highlighted in red), and delete it (as it doesn't exist anymore).

Comment: there are only Data folder, Images.xcassets, and few png and xib files in the Copy Bundle Resources

Comment: Hmmm... have you merged your project from another branch or anything like that? I'm asking because when I did it last time I had similar error and files wasn't visible in bundle resources. I fixed that by doing such steps: right click project file -> show package contents -> open project.pbxproj file. Then I looked for problematic files and deleted such lines.

Comment: I just found that there is similar problem with similar answer, see there http://stackoverflow.com/a/11868293/6429711 .

Comment: i didn't find any mention of copypng in that file, i mean project.pbxproj

Answer (score 0):

On image attached to your question I see info that system couldn't copy files LaunchScreen-iPhoneLandscape.png and LaunchScreen-iPhonePortrait.png.

Normally, if you have Images.xcassets in project there should be "LaunchImage" image set. But it is alsoo possible that these .png files are placed directly in resources. Name for launch image used by target is set in "Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name" in target's Build Settings. Make sure name for Launch image in xcassets (or in .png file in targets sources) matches.

If they are, check if target membership is correct (otherwise they won't be seen by compiler). Last thing to check - check potential problems with LaunchImage files according to the instructions in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11868293/6429711)  from [Adamsor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6429711/adamsor) comment.

For example - check if all necessary file sizes are in place, try opening and re-saving these images in editor. Maybe format is not right and that will be enough to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I've reinstalled XCODE and now all is ok.